# Silent notifications except for specific contacts

Tags: notifications, android-10

I have a Android 10 Huawei phone and only want the phone to ring when specific people call. However I do want to keep onscreen notifications and the LED to pulse (which is working atm).

It seems like like Android 10 is very limited in its emergency contact/favorites settings. I have managed to set a favorite contact who can call even on ***Do Not Desturb*** but the phone will only vibrate eventho the sound is on. I rather not use DND and prefer regular silent mode since all notifications are how I want them.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction, or perhaps recommend an app that can solve this issue?